# onDataChange not called when trying to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to recieve all the data from my Realtime Firebase Database. I would like to loop through this data and store them into Event objects. In addition to this i'm storing these objects into an ArrayList of events.

I need the events because i want to put markers of these events on a Google map. However when i just run the application the markers wont show up because the OnDataChanged method is not called. I already tried to debug my code but im still new to this so i could be doing something wrong.

I am fairly new to the Realtime Firebase Database so i'm maybe missing something.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

//Location
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
Marker marker;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

//Firebase data
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private String userID;

ArrayList<Event> events;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    events = new ArrayList<>();
    getData();
    placeMarkers();

}
public void getData(){
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("events").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String organisator = ds.child("organisator").getValue(String.class);
                String date = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                String startHour = ds.child("startHour").getValue(String.class);
                String location = ds.child("location").getValue(String.class);
                String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(ds.child("latLng").child("latitude").getValue(Double.class), ds.child("latLng").child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));

                Event event = new Event(name, organisator, date, startHour, location, description, latLng);
                events.add(event);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void placeMarkers() {
    ArrayList<Event> evenementen = new ArrayList<>(events);

    for (Event event : evenementen) {

        MarkerOptions eventMarker = new MarkerOptions();
        eventMarker.position(event.getLatLng());
        eventMarker.title(event.getName());
        marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(eventMarker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my problem had something to do with Firebase working Asynchronous (i know very little about this) but i followed this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg and everything is working fine now.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private static final String TAG = "MapsActivity";
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;

//Location
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
Marker marker;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;

//Firebase data
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference firebaseRootRef;
private DatabaseReference eventsRef;
ArrayList<Event> events;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseRootRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    eventsRef = firebaseRootRef.child("events");
    events = new ArrayList<>();

    readData(this::placeMarkers);


}

private interface FirebaseCallback {
    void onCallback(List<Event> events);
}

private void readData(FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback){
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                String organisator = ds.child("organisator").getValue(String.class);
                String date = ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                String startHour = ds.child("startHour").getValue(String.class);
                String location = ds.child("location").getValue(String.class);
                String description = ds.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(ds.child("latLng").child("latitude").getValue(Double.class), ds.child("latLng").child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));

                Event event = new Event(name, organisator, date, startHour, location, description, latLng);
                events.add(event);
            }
            firebaseCallback.onCallback(events);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    eventsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}


public void placeMarkers(List<Event> eventList) {
    for (Event event : eventList) {

        MarkerOptions eventMarker = new MarkerOptions();
        eventMarker.position(event.getLatLng());
        eventMarker.title(event.getName());
        marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(eventMarker);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
yourAdapter.startListening()
```

inside your fragment's onStart & onResume Methods.

This will call the onDataChanged anyhow...

worked for me.